# ERROR: invalid token 'verify' after the command "rladmin help verify "

Tags: redis

I have installed the redis on my VM. And then I run the commands

```
[root@vm001jeguan ~]# rladmin help verify
```

it shows the following error:

```
[root@dltasvm001jeguan ~]# rladmin help verify
ERROR: invalid token 'verify'
```

Run the following command it works well

```
[root@vm001jeguan ~]# rladmin status
```

Does anyone have met such issue? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to run a new `rladmin` command on an older version of [RLEC](https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise).
For further support please contact us at support@redislabs.com

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you are using correct commands.
You can use `rladmin` then press "enter" and get an easier view.
Also use '`tab`' for command guessing will help you.

[Example from 4.2.1-30 RLEC]

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-65 ~]# rladmin
RedisLabs Admin CLI
Version 4.2.1-30.rhel6

Use <?> for help at any time, <TAB> for command completion.

rladmin>
rladmin>
  cluster  Cluster management commands
  exit     Exit admin shell
  failover Fail-over master to slave
  help     Show available commands, or use help <command> for a specific command
  info     Show information about tunable parameters
  migrate  Migrate elements between nodes
  node     Node management commands
  status   Show status information
  tune     Tune system parameters
  upgrade  Upgrade database version
rladmin>
```